# Feedforward Neural Network Training

Tags: java, machine-learning, neural-network

I am trying to write Feed Forward NN, and I am testing it to learn x*y function using particle swarm optimisation to learn (the PSO algorithm is working) but it won't even get close to learning the function. I have looked over my code so many times, so I don't know if I have just become blind to any obvious mistakes in the NN algorithm!

architecture is an int[] as so {No'Inputs, No'Hidden neurons, No'outputs}
So here I am using {2,3,1} for x*y.

Note - Neuron 0 is added for the bias in the input layer and hidden layers. Activation function is tanh()

```
//takes in array of inputs, and weight vector w
public float[] solve(float[] input, float[] w){

    int max_neurons = 0;
    for(int i =0; i<this.architecture.length; i++){
        max_neurons = this.architecture[i]>max_neurons? this.architecture[i]:max_neurons;
    }
    //layer output arrays
    float[] output = new float[max_neurons+1]; //+1 for bias neuron 0
    float[] output_l = new float[max_neurons+1];
    output[0] = 1; //set bias
    output_l[0] = 1; //set bias
    //setup from input
    for(int i = 0; i<architecture[0]; i++){
        output[i+1] = input[i];

    }
    //iterate through hidden layers
    int hidden_layers = architecture.length-2;
    int vector_index = 0;
    float av = 0;
    for(int l = 1; l<=hidden_layers; l++){
        for(int n = 1; n<=architecture[l]; n++){
            av = 0;
            for(int k = 0; k<=architecture[l-1]; k++){
                av += output[k]*w[vector_index];
                vector_index++;
            }
            output_l[n] = af.activation(av);
        }
        output = Arrays.copyOf(output_l, output_l.length);
    }

    //output layer no activation function
    int l = architecture.length-1;
    for(int n = 0; n<architecture[l]; n++){
        av = 0;
        for(int k = 0; k<=architecture[l-1]; k++){
            av += output[k]*w[vector_index];
            vector_index++;
        }
        output_l[n] = av;
    }
    return Arrays.copyOf(output_l, output_l.length);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First and most important thing, regardless of how you code it, feed-forward multilayer neural network won't learn x*y, especially when data are presented in the form of two continious inputs. Reasons: 1). x * y output is unbounded and normal MLP is not suited for learning such functions. At best, it can only approximate some fixed range of x*y, given properly normalized data 2). To properly learn multiplication, one should represent numbers as binary (one digit per input neuron). See [this paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.41.8288&rep=rep1&type=pdf) for further discussion of using NNs for doing arithmetics.

Conclusion:  x*y is a very poor choice for debugging newly implemented neural net. Consider using logic gates such as AND, OR, XOR instead.

Comment: my thinking was though that under the universal approximation theorem I should be able to approximate the function f(x,y) = xy , because in the end I will be using this to approximate much more complication functions.

Comment: @SamPalmer universal approximation theorem states that MLP can approximate any function on **compact subset** of real coordinate space. Output f(x,y) = x * y  is not compact subset of real numbers (it is not bounded), thus in general universal approximation theorem is not applicable here. Therefore, MLP can only approximate x*y for a certain limited range of x and y. Also, in practice, certain ways of data representation can make learning especially difficult.